# Epoxy that can withstand up to 800C and is optically transparent?

Tags: temperature, radiation, epoxy, photonics

I'm looking to use an epoxy in a high-temp environment like 800C, and one that is optically transparent at 450nm (not below 90% transmission). But i'm having trouble finding one. It can be made of any material, as long as it can be cured in a mold.

Comment: Are you using the epoxy as just an edge sealant/adhesive or is the epoxy going to be some kind of surface/ window ? If the latter you should use a high temp glass, the technology for molding glass is well established.

Comment: What's the application? Perhaps there's another solution.

Comment: There are some crazy-expensive specialty epoxies that go up to about 600 C. They require all kinds of silly special handling and curing procedures. So basically, no.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go for glass and casting.

High temp silicones and epoxies don't go to 800 deg C and they are not clear anywhere near their high temperature variants.  Closest I know is a murky clear "crystallized silicone" that goes to 900 deg F.

Ceramic "adhesives" are granular and won't be clear.

Molten glass and a mold are the closest for your optical and temperature needs.  You might be able to get away with pressurizing and heating a powdered glass (aka a silica ceramic) to try and make it clear, but 90% optical transmission is pretty demanding to the point where something molten might be required.

Answer (score 0):

since cured epoxy is a carbon-based polymer, you will have a very hard time finding one that can stand 800C. Have you considered a sintered ceramic?

Comment: With 90% optical transmission?

Comment: Yeah, near-100% fully dense and optically transparent sintered ceramics have been around for ~40 years. Not used much but they do exist.

Comment: I want to see some of this mythical material

Comment: A link to an example material would improve this answer.